# How to install grub on existing Lubuntu installation?

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I have `Lubuntu 16.04` on an USB flash. It kinda worked, but `grub` failed to be installed.

Now I'm struggling to install `grub`.

I'm in the live cd right now. Any ideas what I should do?

I tried to mount the partition and run:

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

but this failes with

```
The file /mnt/boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly..
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Stage1 is from grub (now grub legacy) not grub2?? Are you trying to install old version of grub. Flash drive would probably not be sda as that usually is internal drive. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System Many find Boot-Repair works: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred I installed `grub2` and that worked. That was a very useful tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mount the local drive, [set up a chroot environment](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UtbYJXWJAjA) and install grub on it.

1. Mount the partition you will be using as `/` (I will call the drive `/dev/sdb` and the `/` partition `sdb1`, **the names may be different on your system, you will need to use the correct ones**) somewhere :

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/foo
   ```
2. Bind the directories that `grub` needs to have access to

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/foo/dev && 
   sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev/pts && 
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/foo/proc && 
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/foo/sys
   ```
3. Set up the `chroot` environment

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt/foo
   ```
4. Create grub's configuration file:

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

   If you have multiple operating systems installed, make sure that the command above lists all of them. For example:

   ```
   $ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   Generating grub.cfg ...
   Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-2-amd64
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.10-2-amd64
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-2-amd64
   Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
   Found memtest86+ multiboot image: /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
   Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
   done
   ```
5. Now install grub to the MBR of your drive (remember to change `/dev/sdb` to whichever drive you actually want to install it on)

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sdb
   grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
   ```
6. Exit the `chroot` and unmount everything so your running system is back to normal:

   ```
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt/foo/dev/pts /mnt/foo/dev /mnt/foo/proc /mnt/foo/sys /mnt/foo
   ```
7. Try booting from the drive, you should have a grub menu this time.

Comment: How do you know that OP installed in legacy-mode? Only then this will work.

Comment: @mook765 why? I don't really know that much about EFI, but why wouldn't this also work for an EFI install? I'm not saying you're wrong, it's an honest question. Even better, if you know this will fail, could you post a working solution for EFI systems?

Comment: Using EFI, the EFI-System-partition needs to be mounted as well. Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi/376471#376471

Comment: I had to do `sudo apt install grub2` in `chroot` and then it initialized `grub`. Just to make sure, I executed your commands, and in the end it is working. Thank you!