# Create Unallocated Space To Boot Win7 Using GParted

Tags: windows, gparted

I want to install win7 dual boot with ubuntu but I can't create Unallocated Space to boot win7.

I have 2 disk (1 SSD and 1 HDD) and ubuntu (18.04) is installed on SSD. As shown on a picture, I can't create  Unallocated Space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get an unallocated space, you need to resize your existing partition as you intended to do.

To do it,

- hover your cursor over right border marked by a black triange
- click, hold and move its border to the left when two directed arrow appears

But you need to boot from Ubuntu installation CD (Try Ubuntu without installing) and do it with **unmounted** partition.

Also, do not forget to make a backup of your important data.

Note: most probably windows will rewrite your MBR, so prepare to reinstall grub using [chrooting](https://askubuntu.com/a/902876/925971).